# postgres functions and transactions with BEGIN and blocks

Tags: postgresql

I have some questions about how postgres functions and transactions work. I am beginners to transactions and functions .  please help me to understand the following code.

Currently my function looks like this:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION what_do_i_do(
    arg_i jsonb
)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$function$
DECLARE
    rcd RECORD;
    msg text;
    error json;
    b boolean;
    i integer;
    response json;
    
BEGIN

    --block 1
    i = arg_i->>'i';
    
    --block 2
      a_i = arg_i->>'a_i';
    IF arg_i ? 'm' THEN
        b = Not (arg_i->>'m')::boolean;
    ELSE
        b = true;
    END IF;
    
    
    --block 3
    select p.aa abc into rcd
    from p
    where p.pi = i
    limit 1;
  
    --block 4
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
          RAISE '%', msg USING ERRCODE = 'foreign_key_violation';
          Return Null;
    END IF;

    --block 5
    IF b = true and rcd.pa = false THEN 

        --5.1
        UPDATE p set aa = true where pi = i;

        --5.2
        UPDATE e
        SET aa = true, ab = false
        WHERE aai in (select aai from aa where pi = i and zzz = false)
        and dda = false;

        --5.3
        get diagnostics cnt = row_count;

  
    --6
    RETURN response;

--7
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS stack_msg = MESSAGE_TEXT, stack = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
        RAISE WARNING '%: --- Error Stack ---:
        message: %
        context: %
        ', module, stack_msg, stack;

        RAISE;
END;

$function$;
```

The statements can be UPDATE,EXCEPTION or plain SELECT queries based on some_id. As I understand from postgre documentation, all statements in this function are executed as a single transaction and committed at the END

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is exactly your question?

Comment: There is no COMMIT here - and there could be none. Stored functions return a result - and can be invoked inside an outside transaction, but the function code itself can not contain inner transaction(s).